# Yaesu FTM-3200dr Antenna

Tags: antenna, 2m-band, yaesu

I am looking to upgrade my station soon by buying a Yaesu FTM-3200dr mobile 2m radio. I am limited on funds for radio and I don't want to get the wrong type of antenna connector and wast a bunch of money. If anyone knows what type of antenna connector to get or if anyone has an antenna recommendation for this radio.

Comment: Is this for at home or in your car? If your car, are you willing to drill a hole in it?

Comment: It is for my home, I am looking for something small probably.

Comment: Looks like a very nice radio.  You might want to do some more shopping and pick up a nice name brand VHF/UHF radio in a similar price range, because so many repeaters have moved up  to the 440 band.

Answer (score 2):

Page 13 of the [Operating Manual](https://www.yaesu.com/downloadFile.cfm?FileID=9266&FileCatID=263&FileName=FTM%2D3200DR%5FOM%5FENG%5FEH052N100.pdf&FileContentType=application%2Fpdf) says that radio has a fairly standard SO-239 jack and you need a 50 ohm antenna cable with the matching PL-259 plug. This is also commonly (and confusingly) known as a [UHF connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHF_connector).

As far as a specific antenna recommendation, my favorite is the $25 [N9TAX Slim-Jim](http://www.2wayelectronix.com/Vhf-Slim-Jim-Antenna-with-16-or-10-rg-58-VHF-16.htm); just make sure you select "UHF Male pl-259" for the connector. If you decide to go with a dual-band 2m/440 radio or think you might upgrade to one in the future, it's worth the extra couple bucks to get [the dual band version](http://www.2wayelectronix.com/Dual-band-2m-70cm-Slim-Jim-Antenna-with-16-or-10-rg-58-DUAL-16.htm) of that antenna.